# How do I add Multiple Python Interactive Windows in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a second Ipython window in my VS Code Environment.

Answer (score 7):

The response above is longer up-to-date. Now, VS code supports multiple interactive windows: Open settings and search "interactive window mode".

You can select from `single`, `multiple`, `per-file`

see https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/08/13/vs-code-python.aspx

To create another interactive window go to command pallete (`Ctrl+Shift+p`) and search for "Create Interactive Window."

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to say, but currently there can only be one Interactive Window open at a time. We do have an issue filed on allowing multiple windows here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3104

Which you can upvote or comment on if you would like.